# Changing Navigation Bar Title Font in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I've implemented a Navigation Controller for my View Controller with storyboard. Now i want changing navigation bar title font and size with Attribute Inspector but it doesn't work and i don't understand why. Title color changes but font dont.

ps: the color changing is visible only at runtime and not in the storyboard.

[image: Attribute Inspector's properties]

Comment: maybe because font size is set to `0.0`? :) What's the point of this value?

Comment: I can't believe that! Thank you

Comment: having a similar problem, I'm able to make the changes but they don't show up when I run the app.. :-/

Answer (score 30):

You need to select navigation Bar and then you can set relevant properties. Please check attached image. It might help you.

[image]

Comment: Best answer seen till date :D many small features we miss in the mess called Xcode

Answer (score 29):

When I tried to set the font, my font field was grayed out. But all I needed to do was change type to `System` and then again to `Custom`. It worked:-) Now I can choose my custom font

Comment: Genius! Great Trick. I was just searching for this kind of answer only. (y)

Comment: The kind of fun hacks that XCode has. Will be so much fun if you don't lose an hour trying to make it work... :'(

Answer (score 3):

For me Bartłomiej Semańczyk's change to system font & change back trick only works to set the font to a particular system-included font. For custom fonts that I've added, the font face gets set to my custom font but it always gets displayed as size ~16 or so regardless of what size I select in the storyboard.

So the best way I can find to do this is to set `self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes` in the view controller's `viewDidLoad method`.

Note that you don't need to do this in every view controller you push onto this navigation stack, just the first one that gets displayed since it sets the property on the navigationBar itself not on the navigationItem. If you're subclassing UINavigationController already, that's the most logical place to set this but I'd rather not subclass it just for this one line change.

Comment: Thanks, but putting this in the first view controller didn't have any effect, so I had to subclass UINavigationController. This is in iOS 7.1